# Find Closest Coordinates Inside a Circle

Tags: c++, algorithm, coordinates, geometry

I have an X/Y coordinate outside of a circle.
Whats the fastest way to calculate the nearest point within the circle?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWySm.png]

Comment: Hint: it will be at the distance `R` from the center, on the line passing through the center and the given point.

Comment: Just a note on @IgorTandetnik 's comment, there'll be two such points, make sure to pick the closer of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the vector from the circle center to the point, normalize it, multiply it by the circle radius, and add it back to the circle center.

```
xv = x-xc
yv = y-yc
len = sqrt(xv*xv + yv*yv)
multiplier = radius / len
xr = xc + multiplier*xv
yr = yc + multiplier*yv
```